# Prestashop 1.7 Missing name

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have installed a template in my prestashop, in front view I get this error :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   (1/1) SmartyException
>   Source: Missing name
>   in smarty_template_source.php (line 166)

How I can resolve this in my template ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed compatible theme and it was create for prestashop 1.7?

Comment: @AlexanderGrosul do you mean this error is caused by using a Prestashop 1.6 module on a Prestashop 1.7 website?